# как в c# скопировать все из docx (нескольких) в другой docx

Tags: c#, docx

Есть несколько файлов docx, необходимо их собрать в одном файле docx. Ещё точнее, скопировать содержимое одного файла в конец другого файла.

Answer (score 1):

есть библиотека  https://github.com/krustnic/DocxMerge, позволяет склеивать разные вордовские файлы, в один, обертки на java и php есть.

Comment: Еще подсказка: docx - это обычный zip архив.

Comment: угу, а внутри этого зип архива xml файлы. Только не понятно зачем вы это сказали

Comment: и да, мне нужно для си шарпа. А не для пхп или жавы